# Wind direction and speed in a GPS App

Tags: android, gps

How to include Wind direction and speed to a GPS Android App? How to do it? What are all the considerations for getting those wind details? I'm new to gps. So pls excuse my ignorance.

Comment: GPS gives you only coordinates like longitude, latitude, elevation, bearing (direction of movement), speed of movement. Not even all of these in all situations. GPS has nothing to do with weather info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are 12 weather API: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/01/11/12-json-weather-apis/

For instance, with Yahoo:

> > ***yweather***:wind Forecast information about wind. 
> >     **Attributes:**
>
> - chill: wind chill in degrees (integer)
> - direction: wind direction, in degrees (integer)
> - speed: wind speed, in the units specified in the speed attribute of the  yweather:units element (mph or kph).    (integer)

You have to quesry for the wind direction and speed, no way to get it from the build in GPS.

Comment: That is what i too thought pal. Is there any apps already with this functionality added?

Comment: There are a few thousands weather app in Play Store that display wind speed and direction.

Comment: To be specific, from my gps app, i need to query by default the wind details and get it displayed along with all other details. This is what i want to achieve.

Comment: And this is what I answered with 12 different ways to get it.

Comment: Once again, sorry for my ignorance pal.

Comment: Note that, while this is as good as you're going to easily get, comparing GPS and a weather API is comparing apples and oranges. GPS says what is going on right at the device. A weather API, at best, is based on forecast data and weather instrument readings. Those readings may be from kilometers away. Again, this may meet your needs, and it certainly is all you're likely going to be able to do, but it's important to understand the distinction between an on-device sensor (GPS) and the results of a Web service call.

Comment: yes, I didn't explained that because I thought that it was obvious for everybody that a mobile phone cannot read wind direction and speed...

Answer (score 2):

Background Info:
GPS chips support the NMEA protocol.
Either via this protcol or via the chips binary protcoll the GPS data is sent to the smart phones API.

The GPS chip itself does not support current wind direction and strength, but the NMEA protocoll does. (and many other sensors, like water depth, etc.)

So you could buy a wind sensor, somehow communicate with your app (e.g blue tooth),
take the GPS data from the smart phone, take the sensor data from your wind sensor 
and store that all in NMEA messages (1-2 for the location (RMC, GGA), 1 for the wind sensor)

If that is to much work, then do not mix up measured values (GPS) with prognosis (wind)